# Convert video format to Flash Video automatically

Tags: asp.net, flash, video

I need to allow web site users to upload videos to my web site in various common formats. From these I need to convert them to Flash video, and also limit their lengths and size. I need to do this automatically as part of the web site processing.

Is there some simple tool that will allow me to do this? If not, can you point me in a direction that might help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

With [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) you can run the following command to convert input.avi to output.flv for flash:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -acodec mp3 -f flv output.flv
```

Comment: Whilst this approach will certainly work, I would recommend interfacing directly with the DLL.

Comment: @Matt: Is there any documentation for that?

Comment: @aleemb        How to execute the command automatically as the users finish their uploading audio files in the Asp .net environment?

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) or [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) is usually used for this kind of thing.

As you are using asp.net you should really be interfacing with the DLL. There is also a [c# wrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpffmpeg/) available for ffmpeg.

Comment: How to execute the command automatically as the users finish their uploading audio files in the Asp .net environment?

Answer (score 0):

I use ffmpeg and it works perfectly well doing this with my videos.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue recently too, and I didn't want to go down the route of implementing a video conversion backend on the server.

In the end, what seemed like a reasonable compromise would be to make use of a video conversion service supplied by one of the online services - something like [bits on the run's API](http://www.bitsontherun.com/system-apis/), although it is a paid service, seemed like it would straight forward enough to implement as a web service.

However, if this additional cost is not acceptable, then in a PHP world, I would try to use something like [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/). I guess there must be an equivalent in the asp.net world too, but bear in mind that video conversion can potentially take a really long time, and kicking off this process in a web scripting language is not ideal, if you are waiting for the request to finish, or are facing execution timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a server side software like Adobe Flash Media Server. It can convert video automatically to flv on your server.